# How can I replace the default mobile friendly scrollbar with a standard browser scrollbar

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, scrollbar

Ok,

So I have standard sencha-touch panel, and because this application needs to be capable of interaction for both mobile users and desktop(webkit) users, I need this to feel and look like a standard web application. How do I replace the touch scrollbars, with permanent browser scrollbars when browsing with a desktop browser?

I am sure I can workout how to run based on device, but I do not know how to replace the scrollbars. I am running the latest version of sencha touch - 2 beta.

Cheers, Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for any future sencha users this is the workaround I managed to come up with:

Add this function anywhere:

```
var setupPCScrollbar = function(container){
    var isMobile = (navigator.appVersion.toLowerCase().indexOf("mobile") > -1 || navigator.appVersion.toLowerCase().indexOf("ipad") > -1);
    if(!isMobile){
        if(container.isXType('selectfield'))container = container.down('list');// Add support for selectbuttons
        if(!Ext.isFunction(container.getScrollable) || !container.getScrollable() || !Ext.isFunction(container.getScrollable().getScroller))return console.warn("Attempting to apply pc scroller to non-container item");
        container.getScrollable().getScroller().setDisabled(true);
        var scrollContainers = Ext.DomQuery.select('.x-scroll-container', container.element.dom);
        var scrollBars = Ext.DomQuery.select('.x-scroll-indicator', container.element.dom);
        for(var i=0;i<scrollContainers.length;i++)
            scrollContainers[i].style.overflow = "auto";
        for(var i=0;i<scrollBars.length;i++)
            scrollBars[i].style.zIndex = "-1";
    }
}
```

This function will check for mobile/ipad, then if neither of these are found (likely to be pc) then disable sencha touch scrollbar, hide scrollbar and add standard html scrollbar.

This function is used for example as follows and should work on panels, lists, etc:

```
var container = ...
setupPCScrollbar(container);
```

I would like to have this implemented as a plugin, but have no idea how to add it to the 'container' class's constructor.

**note this is a ipad/pc specific app.

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: I am using your code in an application. Works well for Chrome and Safari. Unfortunately, on IE10 64bit Win7 (Desktop), Scrolling behaviour is very strange. Scrolling is creating infinite empty space on top and bottom of the page. Doesn't work well for IE10. Would you have some other idea for IE10 or could this code be extended to work for IE10?

Comment: I am not sure about IE10 sorry, back when I was developing with sencha, I'm not sure if it was even available. Have sinced moved to KendoUI.

Answer (score 1):

HTML/CSS knows nothing about how scroll bars look and function.  All you can really specify is the overflow mode to let the browser know when you want it to allow scrolling.  If setting `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll` doesn't cause the page to render as you expect, you either have to accept it or roll your own JavaScript-based scrolling widgets.

Comment: I guess as much as anything I was wondering if anyone had done this before, or if there is a plugin for the functionality. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I've had to write my own in the past, and it was painful.  I haven't tried any plugins, but http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ looks promising.

Comment: I understand the css, the problem is, I am unsure how to access the scrollbar, remove the DOM/Css for the sencha touch one, and add my own overflow:auto;